# 2009 MacBook Pro 15” Replace battery now with 257 cycles?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I recently picked up a 2009 MacBook Pro 15”. El Capitan is telling me to replace the battery now. Although the battery is at 100 percent and only has 257 cycles on it. Is it really a battery issue for why the MacBook is shutting down after a few seconds (sometimes minutes) without it plugged in? Or is it something else? I also gave a third party application saying that the battery has about 4 minutes left(and going up for some reason), 10.8 years old, the original max is 6500 mAH, the current max is 65035 mAH, and the current charge is 65035 mAH. This app has never done this for me, so I’m not sure what’s wrong.

Comment: A good place to start is the Power On Self Test. Check this out: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Comment: I would but I have reset my hard drive. So I don’t have the software to do that on here.

Comment: Just reinstall macOS and do it although I’m pretty sure you don’t need macOS to do it.

Comment: Another thing, try not to use third party apps. They’re not always good for your Mac!